# Looping for certain count for curl post

Tags: php, loops, curl

I am new here to get answers for my issues, hoping for your kind advice. Thanks in advance.

I have written a HTTP API to send SMS using curl. Everything is working fine, except I am failing to loop and post curl for certain phone numbers. For example: User uploads 50000 phone numbers using excel sheet on my site, I fetch all the mobile numbers from the database, and then post it through CURL.

Now the sms gateway which I send the request accepts only maximum 10000 numbers at once via http api.

So from the 50000 fetched numbers I want to split the numbers to 10000 each and loop that and send curl post.

Here is my code

```
    //have taken care of sql injection on live site
    $resultRestore = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temptable WHERE userid = '".$this->user_id."' AND  uploadid='".$uploadid."' ");
    $rowRestoreCount = mysql_num_rows($resultRestore);
    @mysql_data_seek($resultRestore, 0); 
    $phone_list = "";
    while($rowRestore = mysql_fetch_array($resultRestore))
    {
        $phone_list .= $rowRestore['recphone'].","; 
    }

    $url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?UserName=".urlencode($this->param[userid])."&Password=".urlencode($this->param[password])."&Type=Bulk&To=".urlencode(substr($phone_list, 0, -1))."&Mask=".urlencode($this->sendname)."&Message=Hello%20World";
    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Now, from the `$phone_list`, I need to loop for every 10000 numbers, How can I achieve this?

Its been 2 days, I have tried several things and not getting the result.

Kindly help...

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: I'm going to start off with the obligatory warning about using *mysql* functions. Please consider switching to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

There are a number of different ways you could do this. Personally, I would reconfigure your script to only fetch 10,000 numbers at a time from the database and put that inside a loop. It might look something like this (note that for simplicity I am not updating your mysql* calls to mysqli*). **Keep in mind I didn't run this through a compiler since most of your code I can't actually test**

```
// defines where the query starts from
$offset= 0; 
// defines how many to get with the query
$limit = 10000; 
// set up base SQL to use over and over updating offset
$baseSql = "SELECT * FROM temptable WHERE userid = '".$this->user_id."' AND  uploadid='".$uploadid."' LIMIT ";
// get first set of results
$resultRestore = mysql_query($baseSql . $offset . ', '. $limit);
// now loop
while (mysql_num_rows($resultRestore) > 0)
{
    $rowRestoreCount = mysql_num_rows($resultRestore);
    $phone_list = "";
    while($rowRestore = mysql_fetch_array($resultRestore))
    {
        $phone_list .= $rowRestore['recphone'].","; 
    }

    $url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?UserName=".urlencode($this->param[userid])."&Password=".urlencode($this->param[password])."&Type=Bulk&To=".urlencode(substr($phone_list, 0, -1))."&Mask=".urlencode($this->sendname)."&Message=Hello%20World";
    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    // now update for the while loop

    // increment by value of limit
    $offset += $limit; 
    // now re-query for the next 10000
    // this will continue until there are no records left to retrieve
    // this should work even if there are 50,123 records (the last loop will process 123 records)
    $resultRestore = mysql_query($baseSql . $offset . ', '. $limit);


}
```

You could also achieve this without using offset and limit in your sql query. This might be a simpler approach for you:

```
// define our maximum chunk here
$max = 10000;

$resultRestore = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temptable WHERE userid = '".$this->user_id."' AND  uploadid='".$uploadid."' ");
$rowRestoreCount = mysql_num_rows($resultRestore);
@mysql_data_seek($resultRestore, 0); 
$phone_list = "";

// hold the current number of processed phone numbers
$count = 0;

while($rowRestore = mysql_fetch_array($resultRestore))
{
    $phone_list .= $rowRestore['recphone'].","; 

    $count++;
    // when count hits our max, do the send
    if ($count >= $max)
    {
        $url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?UserName=".urlencode($this->param[userid])."&Password=".urlencode($this->param[password])."&Type=Bulk&To=".urlencode(substr($phone_list, 0, -1))."&Mask=".urlencode($this->sendname)."&Message=Hello%20World";
        //echo $url;
        $ch = curl_init($url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // now reset count back to zero
        $count = 0;
        // and reset phone_list
        $phone_list = '';
    }
}

// if we don't have # of phones evenly divisible by $max then handle any leftovers
if ($count > 0)
{

    $url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?UserName=".urlencode($this->param[userid])."&Password=".urlencode($this->param[password])."&Type=Bulk&To=".urlencode(substr($phone_list, 0, -1))."&Mask=".urlencode($this->sendname)."&Message=Hello%20World";
    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

I notice that you are retrieving the information in $curl_scraped_page. In either of these scenarios above, you will need to account for the new loop if you're doing any processing on $curl_scraped_page.

Again, please consider switching to mysqli or PDO, and keep in mind that there are likely more efficient and flexible ways to achieve this than what you are doing here. For example, you might want to log successful sends in case your script breaks and incorporate that into your script (for example, by selecting from the database only those numbers that have not yet received this text). This would allow you to re-run your script but only send to those who did NOT yet receive the text, rather than hitting everyone again (or maybe your SMS gateway handles that for you?)

**EDIT**

Another approach would be to load all the retrieved numbers into a single array, then chunk the array into pieces and process each chunk.

```
$numbers = array();
while ($rowRestore = mysql_fetch_array($resultRestore))
{
    $numbers[] = $rowRestore['recphone'];
}
// split into chunks of 10,000
$chunks = array_chunk($numbers, 10000);
// loop and process the chunks
foreach ($chunks AS $chunk)
{
    // $chunk will be an array, so implode it with comma to get the phone list
    $phone_list = implode(',', $chunk);

    // note that there is no longer a need to substr -1 the $phone_list because it won't have a trailing comma using implode()
    $url = "http://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?UserName=".urlencode($this->param[userid])."&Password=".urlencode($this->param[password])."&Type=Bulk&To=".urlencode($phone_list)."&Mask=".urlencode($this->sendname)."&Message=Hello%20World";
    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. I tried your second option for `$max=2` option, it sends out only last 2 phone number out of 15 total numbers. Something is really missing. Thanks for taking out time to help me on this.

Comment: its may be we are emptying `$phone_list = '';` thats the reason, it does not sends out the rest of the numbers, I will try and remove that and update you.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a problem in your logic somewhere but without seeing your code I couldn't help. I'll update my answer with one more possibility.

Comment: I also fixed a couple issues with my first suggestion.

Comment: I totally understand, I unless share my 50 functions with several files and more than 3000 lines of code with you, it is not easy to help me with exact result which I am aspiring to achieve it. First suggestion, I cant use, I call the mysql query in other function and I use several service providers in my php application. Hence 1st option is ruled out for me, I thought your latest suggestion should help but it also sent out the entire numbers, it did not restrict to the desired numbers to 10000. I really appreciate taking time to help me and sincerely thank you for the same.